Proof rotation matrix is symmetric when Trace is -1
For a rotation matrix on SO(3), IE 3 dimensional, if the trace is -1 how do you prove it is symmetric?
Intuitively it makes sense as this is 180 degree rotation but I don't see an obvious proof.

Which part are you stuck on? Proving that a special orthogonal linear transformation with trace $-1$ must be a $180^\circ$ rotation, or proving that a $180^\circ$ rotation must be symmetric?

Proving that if the trace is -1 the matrix is symmetric.

I understand that you haven't solved the problem, but you have yourself outlined a midpoint of sorts. I'm wondering whether your issues are getting to the midpoint, or finishing from the midpoint.

I'm not following, since the trace is -1 we know the eigenvector gets reversed, beyond that I don't know.

I should say we also know the eigenvalue is -1 but I don't know to translate this into saying something about the symmetry properties

As stated here Why should the trace of a 3d rotation matrix have these properties? all rotation matrices are similar to:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\
0&\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Similar matrices have same trace so it follows that
$$
\forall R \in SO_3(\mathbb{R}), \exists \, \theta \in \left[ 0, 2\pi\right[\;: \; \mathrm{Tr}(R) = 1 + 2\cos (\theta)
$$
Then $\mathrm{Tr}(R) = -1 \implies \theta = \pi$, hence $R$ is a symmetric.
